# How to add a integer with string and make a Json like format in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

Probably this question is just waste of your time but I could not find a way to format a string.

I have a incoming int parameter, lets consider its 2

I have to concatenate with a string and make a json like format {"Id":2}
I have to keep the {} also

How can I do that?

Comment: so "Id" is the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be to create the json using string formatting

```
var keyName = "Id";
var result= $"{{ \"{keyName}\":{value} }}"; // Where value is incoming parameter
```

You could also achieve this by Serializing a `Dictionary<string,int>`,

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string,int>{{keyName,value}};
var reuslt = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this or the new $ syntax.

```
String.Format("{\"Id\":{0}}",2)
```

Ideally you would have a class with an Id integer property, set a new instance with a value of 2 and simply serialize the class as Json.